# Autohotkey: Convert a function to C# and (&) bitwise operator

Tags: c#

I have a autohotkey function, which I want to convert/port in c#, but not getting any success. below is the function:

```
GetBits(ANumber) ; get string with numbers of enabled bits in a parameter
{
    i = 1
    bit = 1
    result =
    loop
    {
        if(bit = 512)
            break
        if(ANumber & bit)
            result = %result% %i%
        bit := 2 * bit
        i := i + 1
    }
    return result
}
```

specifically, what does this line mean?

```
if(ANumber & bit)
```

what will be it's equivalent in c#? can anyone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line `if(ANumber & bit)` is doing a logical `AND` and checking if the value is true (non-zero) or false (0)

C# equilent to the line is quite similar

```
if((ANumber & bit) != 0 )
```

this would check the if the result is non zero to pass the condition.

for more info see **[& Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)**

**Full Code**

I attempted to convert full code. data types are based on best guess, you may adjust as necessary.

```
    string GetBits(int ANumber) // get string with numbers of enabled bits in a parameter
    {
        int i = 1;
        int bit = 1;
        string result = string.Empty;
        while (true)
        {
            if (bit == 512)
                break;
            if ((ANumber & bit) != 0)
                result += i.ToString();
            bit = 2 * bit;
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

see if this what you are looking for.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use string concatenation in loops. Even with just 8 bits to deal with, it's a very large number of temp objects and mem copies if this method gets called with any frequency. It is much better to use `StringBuilder` for these kinds of operations.

Comment: Thanks a millions dear pushpraj, you resolved my question completely, the function is working quite accurately.

Comment: That's great! @AkashKakkar, I am glad to be your assistance, happy coding :)